# O365 prompting for password in Outlook 2016 constantly, won't take log in info but is still able to send and receive email

Tags: email, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, email-client

I have an Office 365 account set up with two email accounts under one profile in Mail 32 in control panel.

Every time Outlook 2016 is open it prompts for just one of the accounts passwords, I enter the password in and it is just a never-ending loop.

I cancel that menu and I am able to send and receive email on both accounts. I left click on the "Need password icon" at the bottom right and I can clear the message and it will just say "Connected to Microsoft Exchange".

Additionally, that clears it or sending and receiving email. Seems like a false positive, and this is also a brand new set up. Lots of emails in both accounts, but these accounts are newly added to the Outlook. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you add a sceenshot of the error message and your accounts setup? Giving your question some form besides that of one long paragraph will make it easier to read.

Comment: @harrymc there is no error message, just a never ending loop after entering the password in.

Comment: Sorry, I meant password prompt (to be sure it's the normal one).

Comment: Try this: Open Control Panel -> Credential Manager and remove all passwords related to Office or Office 365.

Comment: @SteveFan you were correct, that was what it was required to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just got the same problem with three different clients: Mailflow working without a problem, but password prompt always pops up again... it seems to be a problem with an Exchange-/Windows-Update, not sure...

Outlook tries to connect to outlook.office365.com even the account isn't hosted there (see credential manager). This registry entry solved the problem:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover]
"ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: I've also see this issue in the case where Exchange is not hosted at O365, but elsewhere. Did this reg entry work after Outlook 2016 got an update in Oct 2018 (with the new icons) and became just "Outlook" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you dont have any add ins which is trying to authenticate to the server and failing.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same problem & spent a while searching for a solution. Some of the things I did where:

- I deleted the account & tried to re-register the account in outlook, it but that failed,
- I read somewhere disabling IPv6 helped but in my case, had no effect
- I considered the MS Docs article: [Outlook continually prompts for your password when you try to connect to Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/sign-in/continually-prompts-password-office-365) but I was using the most up to date Outlook Client with automatic updates so I ignored all this wonderful fiddling about.

It then dawned on me that MS recently made a push for 'Multi-factor' authentication, i.e  better user security, which think many of us may agree with is not a bad idea. I had activated this function some weeks ago. Unfortunately, this W/E I my mobile phone died a death and the authentication service no longer could reach the app for secondary authentication. Consequently, I kept receiving the authentication prompt.

The solution I applied (which may help some of you guys out there & save you some time :) was

- Log into the Office 365 admin Center
- Navigate to Users | Active users & select the 'Multi-factor authentication' tab a the top
- Find the effected user & disable the 'Multi-factor authentication status'
- Wait 5 minute, pray & hopefully it's solved

After which I could re-register the account I had happily deleted & reach the exchange server

This may not be the solution for all, but perhaps for some.

Good luck,

Porky